# Configure SSL for Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, https, redirect, apache2

I want to redirect HTTPS connections to my domain towards a unique subdomain using Apache2 reverse proxy. I want all the connections that come to a.example.com to be redirected towards $random$.b.example.com. To generate the random value I have a script running on port 3000, all requests for a.example.com are proxied to my script which sends back a reply to client with the 302 redirect code and the new domain $random$.b.example.com and then all connections towards $random$.b.example.com are supposed to be served normally.

I have key and certificates for a.example.com and $random$.b.example.com (wildcard certificate *.b.example.com).
However when my client receives the redirect it throws `invalid peer certificate: CertNotValidForName` and does not move on to query $random$.b.example.com. What am I doing wrong?

My virtual hosts look like this:

```
IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName a.example.com

                SSLProxyEngine on
                ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
                ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log vhost_combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard_domain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard_domain.key
        </VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName b.example.com
                ServerAlias *.b.example.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log vhost_combined
                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard_domain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard_domain.key

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                Alias /data /path/to/data
                <Directory /path/to/data>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get means that the subject alternative names in the certificate do not match the hostname from the URL you visit.

According to your config you seem to use the same certificate both for `a.example.com` and `*.b.example.com`. You get this error then because the certificate is not valid for both domains, i.e. you either get the certificate error before the redirect (when visiting `a.example.com`) or after (when visiting `whatever.b.example.com`).

The fix is to either use a certificate which covers both names or use two different certificates in your configuration, one for `a.example.com` and another which covers  `b.example.com` and `*.b.example.com`. Note that a certificate for `*.example.com` will cover only `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` but not `*.b.example.com`.

Comment: I have two different certificates: one for a.example.com and another one for *.b.example.com but how do I combine the two given the configuration above?

Comment: @Mnemosyne: if you have two different certificates then set SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile to the certificate matching the specific VirtualHost instead of using the same certificate for both VirtualHost

Comment: hello, i changed the certificates in the first VH to match the original domain and i dont get this error anymore. Thank you! My new issue is that the path to get the data is now the new $random$.b.example.com/data instead of a.example.com/data (same IP as a.example.com) but the data is no longer accessible under the new domain. Do you have any idea how to fix this in the Directory directive? Thank you again for any suggestions.

Comment: @Mnemosyne: *"My new issue ..."* - please open a new question for this with all necessary details. From this short comment alone I'm not able to understand the problem.